# Select anchor which have no i child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to select a tag which child is not `i`?

Example:

```
<a href="#"> <!--select this-->
   Link!
</a>

<a href="#"> <!--but not this-->
   <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
</a>
```

I tried `a:not(>i)` and `a:empty` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It, most unfortunately, isn't. [It's been proposed](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/), but that's about it.
You would need a bit of js.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a"),
i = 0, ii = links.length;
for (i; i,ii; i++) {
    if(!links[i].querySelector("i")){
        links[i].classList.add("without-i");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been searching around and that's it, there is no way. Thank you for linking the propose :)

Answer (score 2):

Define 2 styles. One for `a`, another one of `a i`. It seems there is no other way around it as `:not` does not allow for combinations.

https://jsfiddle.net/rnu83ogm/1/

```
a{
  color:red;
}
a i{
  color:blue;
}
```

or work with jQuery:

```
$("a:not(:has(>i))")
```

Comment: The problem is that with that method, the selected element would be the `i` tag, not the anchor. In my case, I need to add a padding to the anchors, so it is a definitely problem :(

Comment: sorry Malork :( either JS or do some magic like: `a: padding;   a>i negative-padding-on-i` :(